# Can't delete shortcut from CMD

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, shortcuts

I can't delete shortcut file from CMD, saying file doesn't exist. But if I open Desktop it exists and I can delete it. I tried to copy and I saw something strange, If i copy it to same place, created new shortcut with same name, but if I try it second time it name is changing

[IMAGE - Shotcut name changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Q5c.png)

On CMD:

[IMAGE - Can not find C:\Users\Bosty\Desktop\PC Remote Receiver.lnk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWPR.png)

I just need to remove this shortcut after installing, it is NSIS Package and I'm using silent mode with bat file, i searched blocking shortcut creation on installing but i can not found it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of wildcards:

```
DEL "C:\adjust\path\shortcut_name.*"
```

**Bare in mind:** this is just a workaround and will delete every file with the same name in the target directory!

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not shown, even if you have set *not* to hide extensions in Explorer, all link files have the extension **.lnk**.

If you create a shortcut to Notepad that appears to be `notepad.exe`, to delete it from a command prompt, enter:

`del notepad.exe.lnk`

Comment: I know it, it showing on explorer, but other programs can't seeing it, i think it is not normal shortcut